# How do I use only NAND operators to express OR, NOT, and AND?

Tags: logic

> How do I use only NAND operators to express OR, NOT, and AND?

I assume that AND would just be not NAND, but how to do the others?

Comment: NOT x is x NAND x. Finally for OR use de Morgan

Comment: NOT x = x NAND x ... x AND y = (x NAND y) NAND (x NAND y) ... x OR y = NOT(NOT x AND NOT y), just replace NOT and AND by the formula with NAND

Comment: If all else fails, NAND is also known as the Sheffer stroke, and you can easily find a great deal of information about it under that name.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic

Comment: NAND and XNOR are universal gates. All the other basic gates can be created just using NAND gates.

Comment: @vvgiri The NOR gate is unversal, not the XNOR.

Comment: Yes indeed. mistyped that NAND and NOR it is.